# Sort outer object based on inner array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I need to render a cards based on a array of objects from the API response, which look like this (simplified):

```
[
{
    name: 'John',
    vouchers: [
        {
            voucherId: 1,
            issuedAt: '2020-12-15T16:26:36.3548091+01:00'
        },
        {
            voucherId: 2,
            issuedAt: '2020-12-15T16:26:36.3548091+01:00'
        },
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Lisa',
    vouchers: [
        {
            voucherId: 1,
            issuedAt: '2020-12-13T16:26:36.3548091+01:00'
        }
    ]
}]
```

Now I want to NgFor over this array of objects (with in it an array of objects) and sort (the outer object) based on the 'issuedAt' date.

note: the issuedAt date for the array of vouchers is always the same for each user.

I was thinking of some combination of using .map => .sort => Number(new Date(DATE_HERE)), but couldn't get it to work

Comment: "couldn't get it to work" - could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: As you said you have to do a .sort on your array, and in your template html just to the ngFor on this array and it's done. Check the sort doc to see how to sort an array of object

Comment: So, in this case, you want it to be sorted as "John", then "John"? :)

Comment: @chazsolo what I made didn't make a lot of sense, for sure was nog the right way to do it. I tried to map over the response (storing it) and then sorting the vouchers, however, this obviously sorts the inner array ' vouchers'.

Comment: @HereticMonkey 2nd John now goes trough life as 'Lisa'. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the person with the most-recent time to be listed first, get the max issue date for all vouchers and subtract them.

**Note:** I changed the hours so that sorting actually works.

```js
const result = [{
  name: 'John',
  vouchers: [{
    voucherId: 1,
    issuedAt: '2020-12-15T16:26:36.3548091+01:00'
  }, {
    voucherId: 2,
    issuedAt: '2020-12-15T17:26:36.3548091+01:00'
  }, ]
}, {
  name: 'John',
  vouchers: [{
    voucherId: 1,
    issuedAt: '2020-12-13T18:26:36.3548091+01:00'
  }]
}];

const sorted = result.sort(
  ({ vouchers: a = [] }, { vouchers: b = [] }) =>
    Math.max(...a.map(({ issuedAt: d = 0 }) => new Date(d))) - 
    Math.max(...b.map(({ issuedAt: d = 0 }) => new Date(d)))
);
  
console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Note that `new Date(d)` is fairly expensive, when the input format is already comparable.

Also note that the question mentioned that all dates within a voucher array is the same, so the `Math.max` call is not really necessary.  You could just use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the array of vouchers all have the same `issuedAt` property, you should be able to do this just using the first entry:

```js
const data = [{name: 'John', vouchers: [{voucherId: 1, issuedAt: '2020-12-15T16:26:36.3548091+01:00'}, {voucherId: 2, issuedAt: '2020-12-15T16:26:36.3548091+01:00'}]}, {name: 'Lisa', vouchers: [{voucherId: 1, issuedAt: '2020-12-13T16:26:36.3548091+01:00'}]}]

const sorter = ({vouchers: [{issuedAt: x}]}, {vouchers: [{issuedAt: y}]}) => 
  x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0

console .log ([...data] .sort (sorter))
```

We use `[...data]` as a cheap shallow clone; I prefer not to mutate input data.  But you could just call `data .sort (sorter)` if you actually want to mutate your array.

Answer (score 0):

used Date.parse() to get milliseconds from date string

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'John',
    vouchers: [{
        voucherId: 1,
        issuedAt: '2020-12-15T16:26:36.3548091+01:00',
      },
      {
        voucherId: 2,
        issuedAt: '2020-12-15T16:26:36.3548091+01:00',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Lisa',
    vouchers: [{
      voucherId: 1,
      issuedAt: '2020-12-13T16:26:36.3548091+01:00',
    }, ],
  },
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (
    Date.parse(a['vouchers'][0]['issuedAt']) -
    Date.parse(b['vouchers'][0]['issuedAt'])
  );
});

console.log(data)
```